# Is there a way I can integrate my app into WhatsApp as an additional feature?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I'm working on an Android app that selects multiple contacts / all contacts with one tap. It works pretty much like how "Select All" works in Gallery. However, I was wondering if I could integrate it in WhatsApp as a feature of it. I know WhatsApp is not open source, but I was wondering if there's any way in which my app could be invoked from WhatsApp every time I tried to select a contact / all contacts?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: no it´s not possible, only you have an agreement with the developers of whats app....

Comment: only thing you can do is to show your app in IntentChooser dialog

Comment: Well maybe, and i say maybe, its possible to your app to be called from the intent whatsapp should be sending to launch the contact app (mostly what vivek says).